# Qt - How to connect signal from loader item, if loader source changes dynamically

Tags: qt, qml

I have an application which needs the screen to be switched between multiple available screens. I am checking if this is possible with loader in qml.

The issue i am facing is connecting signals from loaded item.

I use an application example in qt documentation and found CreateConnection in application qml cannot have if condition.

I also tried to make it signal slot connection in a function and call in on source change of loader, but that too did not work.

Application.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Item {
    width: 100; height: 100

    Loader {
       id: myLoader
       source: "MyItem.qml"
    }

    Connections {
        target: myLoader.item
        // here i tried using if (myLoader.item == "qrc:MyItemOne.qml") , but can't use if
        onChangeToSecond: {
               myLoader.source = "MyItemTwo.qml"
        }

        onChangeToFirst: {
               myLoader.source = "MyItemOne.qml"
        }
    }
}
```

MyItemOne.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
   id: myItem
   signal changeToSecond()

   width: 100; height: 100

   MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent
       onClicked: myItem.changeToSecond()
   }
}
```

MyItemTwo.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
   id: myItem
   signal changeToFirst()

   width: 100; height: 100

   MouseArea {
       anchors.fill: parent
       onClicked: myItem.changeToFirst()
   }
}
```

Someone knows any way to use loader for this, or loader should not be used for this?

Comment: `Loader` should not be used for this (at least not in common cases). If you have multiple screens just use [`StackView`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qt-labs-controls-stackview.html).

Answer (score 2):

Your code works fine if I use `MyItemOne.qml` as the initial value for the `myLoader.source` (Qt5.6.0). However, it will print out a warning:

```
QML Connections: Cannot assign to non-existent property "onChangeToFirst"
```

which happens because  `MyItemOne` does not define the `changeToFirst` signal. The `ignoreUnknownSignals` property of `Connections` element can be used to suppress the warning, or both screens should define the same set of signals.

`Loader` can be used if it does not matter that the previous view is always fully unloaded when switching.